# Pre-filled Google form with varying number of questions

Tags: google-forms

So I am doing a client check in...some clients have 5 things about which I need a status, some have only 1.  How/Can I create a Google form with pre-filled answers and questions that would vary by client?

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, you'll need a page for each client type that requires specific questions. In this [example](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1IdJ7XOnxNBYjsq3XaTfnqr6WBBg8YxiQHQDPJNSSdDA/formResponse), I have three types (ninja, potato, elk).

You'll make a page for each unique question(s)/client type paring. I made two pages. One for ninjas and one for potatoes. (elks can't type). You can see in the screenshot below that I checked the box that says `Go to page based on answer` and then set the questions so they'd go to the correct pages.

[image]

You can pre-fill answers to specific questions via URL.

[Open the form.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160000?hl=en&rd=1)

1. In the top right, click the More icon.
2. Choose Get pre-filled link.
3. Fill in any answer fields you want to pre-populate.
4. Click Submit.
5. To send the pre-populated form to respondents, use the link at the top.